# Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix'

Tags: mono, rhel, mono-posix

I'm attempting to run an exe on RHEL 6 using Mono.  I've compiled Mono 4.0.2.4 and when I try to run my exe it crashes.

My Command:

```
/opt/mono/bin/mono /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe -l:plexos.lock ./DALicenseServer.exe
```

The Error.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
```

I think I have the Mono.Posix.dll file:

```
ls /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.0/Mono.Posix.dll
/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.0/Mono.Posix.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug (Bug 56787) currently tracked by the Xamarin team. You must download and paste the missing dll in your environment then restart visual studio.

for vs 2015 paste here the dll: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin\

for vs 2017 paste here the dll: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio

check this link for step by step: https://releases.xamarin.com/common-issues-in-the-xamarin-15-2-2-release-being-tracked-by-the-xamarin-team/

Answer (score 0):

1) Try running mono with trace mode to see if it really is `Mono.Posix.dll` or a native shared library (.so) that is not being found.

```
mono --trace /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mono-service.exe -l:plexos.lock ./DALicenseServer.exe
```

2) Check to see if the assembly has been installed properly in the GAC:

```
gacutil -l Mono.Posix

The following assemblies are installed into the GAC:
Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756
Number of items = 1
```

3) If the assembly is not found in the GAC, something went wrong during the install (`make install`) as this assembly is part of the framework install. You can manually assign the MONO_PATH to tell `mono` where it should find assemblies that are not in the current directory ($PWD) and/or not in the GAC:

```
export MONO_PATH=/path/to/assemblies:/another/path/to/assemblies:$PATH
```